# Show correct PHP JSON output from unicode data

Tags: php, json, unicode, encoding, beautifulsoup

Me and my friend is developing a python scraper which uses `Beautifulsoup 4` to parse a website. We filter parts of the page and "print" this output from the python script.

Which is, in fact, executed by `PHP`. However, we have a hard time figuring out the classical encoding problems. By default, `Beautifulsoup` returns unicode data. And that is what we forward to the`PHP` script.

What we want to do now is to parse the output and encode it as valid `JSON`. In this process we do not want to have the unicode representative  in the output, but their `utf-8` equivalent.

Parts of the output from the php script looks like this:

```
["{"," \"course_count_grade\": 24,"," \"course_count_pass\": 3,"," \"course_count_pending\": 5,"," \"course_count_total\": 32,"," \"course_credits_grade\": 0.0,"," \"course_credits_pass\": 0.0,"," \"course_list_grade\": ["," {"," \"comment\": \"\\u00a0\","," \"course_id\": \"DM2571\","," \"course_name_sv\": \"Framtidens medier\","," \"credits\": \"\","," \"credits_registered\": \"10.0\","," \"date\": \"2013-12-27\","," \"details\": ["," {"," \"comment\": \"\\u00a0\","," \"credits\": \"\","," \"credits_registered\": \"1.5\","," \"date\": \"2013-12-20\","," \"detail_id\": \"\\u00a0LABA\","," \"detail_name_sv\": \"Laborationer\","," \"grade\": \"P\""," }"," ],"," \"grade\": \"A\""," },"," {"," \"comment\": \"\\u00a0\","," \"course_id\": \"DM2572\","," \"course_name_sv\": \"Teori och metod f\\u00f6r Medieteknik\","," \"credits\": \"\","," \"credits_registered\": \"7.5\","," \"date\": \"2013-12-20\","," \"details\": ["," {"," \"comment\": \"\\u00a0\","," \"credits\": \"\","," \"credits_registered\": \"7.0\","," \"date\": \"2013-12-27\","," \"detail_id\": \"\\u00a0PRO1\","," \"detail_name_sv\": \"Projekt\","," \"grade\": \"A\""," },"," {"," \"comment\": \"\\u00a0\","," \"credits\": \"\","," \"credits_registered\": \"3.0\","," \"date\": \"2013-12-27\","," \"detail_id\": \"\\u00a0LIT1\","," \"detail_name_sv\": \"Litteraturuppgift\","," \"grade\": \"P\""," }"," ],"," \"grade\": \"B\""," },"," {"," \"comment\": \"\\u00a0\",
```

I have tried different options for the `PHP` `json_encode()` function like `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`, to no avail.

Any tip on what I might do wrong?

**Update:**
@Len_D, Yes, I'm executing my python scripts like this:
`exec($command, $output);`
Then I take the out out and return it. When I try to do as you proposed: `utf8_decode($output);` I get an error saying "utf8_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given". I then tried this: `utf8_decode(json_encode($output));` This gives me an output, but it the same as before:

```
["{"," \"course_count_grade\": 24,"," \"course_count_pass\": 3,"," \"course_count_pending\": 5,"," \"course_count_total\": 32,"," \"course_credits_grade\": 0.0,"," \"course_credits_pass\": 0.0,"," \"course_list_grade\": ["," {"," \"comment\": \"\\u00a0\","," \"course_id\": \"DM2571\","," \"course_name_sv\": \"Framtidens medier\","," \"credits\": \"\","," \"credits_registered\": \"10.0\","," \"date\": \"2013-12-27\","," \"details\": ["," {"," \"comment\": \"\\u00a0\","," \"credits\": \"\","," \"credits_registered\": \"1.5\","," \"date\": \"2013-12-20\","," \"detail_id\": \"\\u00a0LABA\","," \"detail_name_sv\": \"Laborationer\","," \"grade\": \"P\""," }"," ],"," \"grade\": \"A\""," },"," {"," \"comment\": \"\\u00a0\","," \"course_id\": \"DM2572\","," \"course_name_sv\": \"Teori och metod f\\u00f6r Medieteknik\",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put these headers `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: Tried that, made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the php functions utf8_decode: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_xml_utf8_decode.asp

And utf8_encode: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_xml_utf8_encode.asp

Comment: Try to be more specific and how I might use that in this context. This doesn't really help.

Comment: I assume you are taking the output and storing it in a php variable like $output = '...'. If you are, then use $output = utf8_decode(...) and the UTF symbols will be replaced with  ISO-8859-1 characters. Am I understanding your problem correctly?

Comment: Since an array is being returned, seems like you need to walk through each element of the array and apply utf8_decode to the element and then update the array.